Identify the movie with men celebrating something in the shower
Please help me to identify the movie in this video clip.
Please note, the following video is NSFW as it contains strong language:
http://coub.com/view/n4ij

The song is from Flight of the Conchords. Is this definitely a movie scene and not a commercial/comic video?

@AndrewMartin I know about the song, it was easy to identify :) And I am not sure that this is the scene from movie.

No worries. Well that's about as far as I can help with. I just remember the episode. Hopefully someone else can help.


Vive la France (2013)

Tired of his small country not getting any international respect, the
  dictator of Taboulistan, proud of his country's original recipe for
  taboulé that is unjustly attributed to Lebanon, decides to remedy the
  situation by having the Eiffel Tower blown up. 
The mission is given to two naïve shepherds, Feruz and Muzafar, who
  will be faced with the worst challenge that France has to offer: the
  French.

~ Synopsis taken from CiNEMAN; Movie Poster from IMP Awards
Watch the trailer to confirm.
